# JavaScript regex: Find a tag and get some attribute values

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, match

i need to capture a html tag by class and some attribute value.

I've resolved the first part, capturing the tag by class (the `querySelector` should be something like: `'input.hashtag'`):

```html
<input type="text" value="#tag3" notified="true" class="label-primary hashtag">
```

So, im using this regex:

```js
/(?=<input[^>]+(?=[\s+class=\"]hashtag[\s+\"]).+)([^>]+>)/g
```

You can checkout the test here https://regex101.com/r/zY4sH9/6

What i need is to capture also the attribute values: `value` and  `nofified`, to finally get:

- match1 `<input type="text" value="#tag3" notified="true" class="label-primary hashtag">`
- match2 `#tag`
- match3 `true`

Comment: Why? Better use a decent library like [jQuery](https://www.jquery.com)

Comment: Cause it will be mixed with some noisy code and parsers like jquery cant match properly... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that you're already using the `.querySelector()` method, therefore I would suggest avoiding regular expressions and using the native DOM methods.

```
var element = document.querySelector('input.hashtag'),
    value = element.value,
    notified = element.getAttribute('notified');
```

Similarly, if you want to select an `input` element that has a `.hashtag` class *and* `value`/`notified` attribute, then you could simply use two attribute selectors `input.hashtag[value][notified]`:

```
var element = document.querySelector('input.hashtag[value][notified]'),
    value = element.value,
    notified = element.getAttribute('notified');
```

---

However, if you need to use regular expressions, the following would capture the `value` and `notified` attribute's value **regardless of order** (since positive lookaheads are being used):

```
/(<input(?=[^>]*[\s+class=\"]hashtag[\s+\"])(?=[^>]*value=\"([^"]+)\")(?=[^>]*?notified=\"([^"]+)\")[^>]*\>)/
```

[**Updated Example**](https://regex101.com/r/pH6cC7/1)

I just built off of your existing expression, so I don't need to explain the first part.

- `(?=[^>]*value=\"([^"]+)\")` - Positive lookahead with a capturing group to match the `value` attribute's value after zero or more non-`>` characters.
- `(?=[^>]*?notified=\"([^"]+)\")` - Positive lookahead with a capturing group to match the `notified` attribute's value after zero or more non-`>` characters.

Capturing groups:

Group 1 - `<input type="text" value="#tag3" notified="true" class="label-primary hashtag">`

Group 2 - `#tag3`

Group 3 - `true`

Answer (score 0):

`.classname` is a class selector, `[propertyname=value]` is a value selector, so you can do something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input.hashtag[notified=true]')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680216/josh-crozier) solved my question, and this is why:

```js
var reg = /(<input(?=[^>]*[\s+class=\"]hashtag[\s+\"])(?=[^>]*value=\"([^"]+)\")(?=[^>]*?notified=\"([^"]+)\")[^>]*\>)/gi;

string.replace(reg, '[$2]($3)');

// prints [#tag3](true)
```

Thanks mate!